# How to check all the documents in a MongoDB database for the latest value of a particular field using aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am new to MongoDB and am working with it on NodeJS code.

I need to use aggregation functions to pull the latest `book_version` of each individual book.

This is how my database looks:

```
[
  {
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "0”,
    "author": “Sam”,
    “name”: “Sample Book”,
    “comments”: “Done”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "1",
    "author": "Martin",
    "name": "Sample Book",
    “comments”: “In Progress”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "2",
    "author": "Roy",
    "name": "Sample Book",
    “comments”: “To-Do”
  }
]
[
  {
    "book_id": "bcj123n”,
    "book_version": "0”,
    "author": “Don”,
    “name”: “Another Book”,
    “comments”: “Done”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "bcj123n”,
    "book_version": "1",
    "author": "Ray",
    "name": "Another Book",
    “comments”: “In Progress”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "bcj123n”,
    "book_version": "2",
    "author": "Max",
    "name": "Another Book",
    “comments”: “To-Do”
  }
]
[
  {
    "book_id": "k23d1d3”,
    "book_version": "0”,
    "author": “Sunny”,
    “name”: “New Book”,
    “comments”: “Done”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "k23d1d3”,
    "book_version": "1",
    "author": "Archer",
    "name": "New Book",
    “comments”: “In Progress”
  }
]
[
  {
    "book_id": "o902f3s”,
    "book_version": "0”,
    "author": “Joy”,
    “name”: “Nice Book”,
    “comments”: “Done”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "o902f3s”,
    "book_version": "1",
    "author": "James",
    "name": "Nice Book",
    “comments”: “In Progress”
  },
{
    "book_id": "o902f3s”,
    "book_version": "2”,
    "author": “Pam”,
    “name”: “Nice Book”,
    “comments”: “Done”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "o902f3s”,
    "book_version": "3",
    "author": "Jonah",
    "name": "Nice Book",
    “comments”: “Completed”
  }
]
```

As a result, I should get the maximum value of `book_version` for each `book_id` along with the entire object:

```
{
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "2",
    "author": "Roy",
    "name": "Sample Book",
    “comments”: “To-Do”
  },
{
    "book_id": "bcj123n”,
    "book_version": "2",
    "author": "Max",
    "name": "Another Book",
    “comments”: “To-Do”
  },
{
    "book_id": "k23d1d3”,
    "book_version": "1",
    "author": "Archer",
    "name": "New Book",
    “comments”: “In Progress”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "o902f3s”,
    "book_version": "3",
    "author": "Jonah",
    "name": "Nice Book",
    “comments”: “Completed”
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by `book_id` and capture lastVersion using [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/index.html) operator. Then you need to [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) all the books belonging to particular group and use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote single found recent version to root level.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$book_id",
            lastVersion: { $max: "$book_version" },
            versions: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        lastVer: {
                            $filter: { 
                                input: "$versions", 
                                cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.book_version", "$lastVersion" ] } 
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$lastVer", 0 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MuFi-fO3PIm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to achieve the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      // Sort by the book_version from highest to lowest 
      book_version: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      // Group the documents by their book_id
      _id: "$book_id",
       book_version: {
        // The first book_version is the highest book version
        // The same thing applies to every other first-of other book fields 
        $first: "$book_version"
      },
      book_id: {
        $first: "$book_id"
      },
      author: {
        "$first": "$author"
      },
      name: {
        "$first": "$name"
      },
      comments: {
        "$first": "$comments"
      }
    }
  }
])
```